# Minecraft Mob-Spawning in vanilla 1.8 server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-commands

I am making my own server and I am trying to make mobs not spawn in a certain area, I can't do a `/kill @e[type=!Player]` command because I have armor stands! So I was wondering what you guys thought. I am playing on a 1.8 vanilla server.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what you're asking here.  Are you asking us if there's a different way to stop monsters from spawning in a certain area?  Or if your way is a good way?

Comment: Torches. Lots of torches.

Comment: `/kill @e[type=Zombie,r=16,0,0,0]` clocks. Along with those for other mobs. Just make sure you don't have a `/kill @e` (kills everything) or a `/kill @e[type=ArmorStand]` clock.

Comment: @aytimothy Could you do something like `/kill @e[type=!ArmorStand]` and `/kill @e[type=!player]`? (I don't do this kind of thing very often)

Comment: @Ben The first one would kill everything except armorstands (including players), and the second one would kill everything except players (including armorstands), so you would just kill everything. I think what lambchop9 wants is something like `/kill @e[type=!Player,type=!ArmorStand]`, unfortunately Minecraft just doesn't allow for more than one type argument.

Comment: Don't think you can simply use ! in the command. You'll need to specify to kill each mob type individually. You can't say kill everything but X and Y.

Comment: Adding a [r=10] selector would mean that all entities excluding the types Player and ArmorStand would be killed *within that certain area*. You can still have mobs spawn elsewhere

Answer (score 4):

1. `/gamerule doMobSpawning false` This will globally disable mob spawning
2. Make sure there are no spots with light level below 7
3. Make the floor with a material where mobs can't spawn on
4. Make sure there are no airspaces around the area in a considerable size (10 blocks i believe) to prevent the start of the spawning sequence.

Comment: I think he wants to rid the spawn area of mobs but still allow mobs to spawn outside.

Comment: *3. Make the floor with a material where mobs can't spawn* Durr. Why didn't I think of that? Haha. Half slabs and (I think) glass are just two blocks that mobs *cannot* spawn on.

Comment: Here is an test on the spawning of mobs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysjYp1NBFyw https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhliRtx0ay0 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fs0Xke8aRKI