# Can "/kill" affect an armour stand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Partially from curiosity, and partially because [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189901/minecraft-mob-spawning-in-vanilla-1-8-server) is unclear as to whether or not this is actually possible.

Does a `/kill` command affect armour stands?

Eg.

```
/kill @e[type=!Player]
```

Comment: Pretty sure it can, since it affects item entities. Let's find out really fast!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Armor stands are entities, so the `@e` selector *(but not `@r`, `@a`, `@p`, etc. which are limited to players)* will select them, and thus `/kill @e`will kill them.

[image]